# How to Move Mediator initialization into base razor page and use base page instead if pageModel in .net-Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, mediatr

> My razor page

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{

```
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;
```

> I want to use another way to initialize mediator instead of doing this in all razor pages

```
  public IndexModel(IMediator mediator)
            {
                _mediator = mediator;           
            }
            public async  Task OnGetAsync()
            {
               var result = _mediator.Send(new AddUserRequest { });
    
            //var result = Mediator.Send(new AddUserRequest { }); // <= Want to use mediator like this  
                                                                   //  How to  create razor base 
                                                                   //  class for this requirement
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You define your base class to hold a protected (or public) property of type IMediator

```cs
public class CustomPageModel : PageModel
{
    public CustomPageModel(IMediator mediator) => Mediator = mediator;
    protected IMediator Mediator { get; }
}
```

Then, inherit the base class like this:

```cs
public class IndexModel : CustomPageModel 
{
   public IndexModel(IMediator mediator) : base(mediator) { }
   public async Task OnGetAsync()
   {
      var result = Mediator.Send(new AddUserRequest {});
   ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this way.

```
 public class BasePageModel : PageModel
{

    private ISender _mediator = null;
    protected ISender Mediator => _mediator ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ISender>();
}
```

Then inheri the base model.  No need to pass mediator to the base class.

```
public class IndexModel : BasePageModel
{
   public void OnGet()
   {
       Mediator.Send(new GetExampleQuery());
   }
}
```